Converting Zustand code to Context API state
I have this piece of code written in typescript for zustand state management library
export const useStore = <T, F>(
  store: (callback: (state: T) => unknown) => unknown,
  callback: (state: T) => F,
) => {
  const result = store(callback) as F;
  const [data, setData] = useState<F>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(result);
  }, [result]);

  return data;
};

how can I convert this piece of code to normal Context API code ?

React hooks and the React Context API are two completely different technologies... one cannot convert one into the other. What is the issue or problem you are trying to solve for that you think conversion is the solution? What are you trying to accomplish? Please [edit] to clarify the issue or problem and what the expected outcome should be.

May I have misunderstanding  about this information.. I mean the context react hook

Create an StoreContext.tsx
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface StoreContextType<T> {
  state: T;
  setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
}

const StoreContext = createContext<StoreContextType<any> | undefined>(undefined);

export const StoreProvider = <T,>({ children, initialState }: { children: ReactNode; initialState: T }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(initialState);

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};

create a custom hook
export const useStore = <T, F>(callback: (state: T) => F): F => {
  const context = useContext(StoreContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useStore must be used within a StoreProvider');
  }

  const { state, setState } = context as StoreContextType<T>;
  const [data, setData] = useState<F>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = callback(state);
    setData(result);
  }, [state, callback]);

  return data as F;
};

wrap the index file with store provider
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { StoreProvider, initialState, AppState } from './StoreContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StoreProvider<AppState> initialState={initialState}>
      <App />
    </StoreProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

use the context in your relevant componenet
type AppState = {
  count: number;
};

const initialState: AppState = {
  count: 0,
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const count = useStore((state: AppState) => state.count);

  return <div>Count: {count}</div>;
};

